# non-compatible bean definition of same name and class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I understand the follow exception stack,but make me confused is that my application run on local dev and qa environment,they run well,but on product environment,got exception when tomcat starts.
anyone can give some clue or suggestion about the exception?

The bean name conflict from two different jars

> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'filter' for bean class [com.alibaba.druid.filter.Filter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.fasterxml.classmate.Filter]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your configuration is slightly different between the environments. Unless the two are *supposed* to be substitutes, give them each a more descriptive name than "filter" so they don't collide.

Comment: the two conflict beans from two jars.the configurations are same.